# reading unicode *.txt files?

Tags: java, android

Currently I am reading .txt files with

```
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(masterPath+txt);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String readLine = null;

        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
        ...
```

But unicode characters do not appear as they should.

Any ideas how to change the above code, for unicode to work?

Thanks!

Comment: also, unicode is not an encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Specify the appropriate encoding when constructing your InputStreamReader. If your file is UTF-8 encoded, use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't cause any errors, yet doesn't decode the unicode either. Yet if I try "UTF-16" or "UTF-16LE" it throws "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Comment: If you don't know what encoding your file uses, we don't either. This is a prerequisite to read the file correctly. Another possibility is that the font you're using to display the read text doesn't contain the glyphs for all the characters of your text.

Comment: @Roger, you'll need to ascertain the encoding to use by checking with the code that wrote the file, or looking at the bytes in the file in a hexdump. Just trying different ones and hoping to chance upon one that happens to work on your test data is not a robust development strategy.

Comment: Then the encoding is probably Windows-1252 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). If your JVM doesn't support this encoding, using ISO-8859-1 as encding name might work (depending on what characters are in the text). Else, convert it to a more cross-platform encoding first.

Comment: tried "ISO-8859-1", but it still doesn't show the character right. how can I convert it to a more cross-platform encoding?

Comment: Reopen it with Notepad, save as, and choose UTF-8 as encoding.

Answer (score 2):

The plain `InputStreamReader` constructor will assume that the file has the system's "default encoding". Because it is rather unpredictable what that is, this constructor should not be used except in toy examples. Use one of the two-argument constructors that allow you to specify the encoding explicitly.

By the way, "Unicode" is not sufficient to tell what is in the file you want to read. Unicode, by and of itself, defines just how numbers ("codepoints") are assigned to characters, not how to pack those numbers into bytes in a file, which is the job of an "encoding". In practice your encoding is likely to be either UTF-8 or UTF-16 or some endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your file isn't unicode encoded, or maybe the way you're displaying it isn't unicode-compliant (Windows cmd.exe, I'm looking at you).